# C#: IEnumerator<T> in a using statement

Tags: c#, ienumerable, idisposable, using-statement, ienumerator

I was curious to see how the `SingleOrFallback` method was implemented in [MoreLinq](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/) and discovered something I hadn't seen before:

```
    public static T SingleOrFallback<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T> fallback)
    {
        source.ThrowIfNull("source");
        fallback.ThrowIfNull("fallback");
        using (IEnumerator<T> iterator = source.GetEnumerator())
        {
            if (!iterator.MoveNext())
            {
                return fallback();
            }
            T first = iterator.Current;
            if (iterator.MoveNext())
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException();
            }
            return first;
        }
    }
```

Why is the `IEnumerator<T>` in a `using` statement? Is this something that should be thought about when using the `foreach` on an `IEnumerable<T>` also?

*Side question:* What does this method do exactly? Does it return the fallback item whenever the source sequence does not contain exactly one item?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`IEnumerator<T>` extends `IDisposable`, so you *should* have it in a using statement. `foreach` does this automatically. (The non-generic `IEnumerator` *doesn't* extend `IDisposable` but the C# compiler still generates code to call `Dispose` conditionally. This was one of the (few) changes between C# 1.0 and 1.2, where 1.2 is the version shipping with .NET 1.1, for some reason.)

[Here's an article](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter6/IteratorBlockImplementation.aspx) explaining why this is important in the context of iterator blocks.

As for what the method does:

- If the sequence is empty, return the fallback item
- If the sequence has exactly one item, return it
- If the sequence has more than one item, throw an exception

PS: Nice to see MoreLinq is getting some attention :)

Comment: Hehe, yeah. Added it to our project because of the MaxBy and MinBy methods. And when adding something like that, you always have to check if there is anything else you can use ;)

Comment: Not sure what this SingleOrFallback method is useful for though... could you explain what you use it for? Understand what it does now, but not when you would use such a method :p

Comment: Sure: suppose you've got a search which should return a single result, if any. You want to have some sort of default for if it doesn't return  anything, but die if there's more than one result (as that indicates a bug). Basically it's SingleOrDefault but with a specified default value as a function which won't get called unless it's needed.

Comment: Aha. But SingleOrDefault contains a predicate as well, right? So to use this SingleOrFallback, you would use for example Where(predicate) and then SingleOrFallback?

Comment: SingleOrDefault has an overload with a predicate, yes. We could add one to SingleOrFallback as well if desired - but otherwise Where would do fine.

Answer (score 0):

Some enumerators will behave badly if Dispose is not called; this is just as true for the non-generic ones as the generic ones (the non-generic ones require that code either duck-type the Dispose call or else cast to IDisposable and then call IDisposable.Dispose).  It is good as a matter of habit to ensure that IEnumerator objects get disposed; I would consider it necessary for correctness of any routine which accepts an IEnumerable of unknown type.